# unable to bind to requested udp port 43210 (ipv4)

Tags: games, port-forwarding

I'm trying to run "BombSquad" game it requires to bind to udp port 43210 , i have no idea how to bind to udp port.
i ran `./bombsquad_server` command

this is the output:

```
bombsquad server wrapper starting up...
tip: enter python commands via stdin to reconfigure the server on the fly:
example: config['partyName'] = 'New Party Name'
FATAL ERROR: unable to bind to requested udp port 43210 (ipv4)
BombSquad exited with code 255  
FATAL ERROR: unable to bind to requested udp port 43210 (ipv4)
BombSquad exited with code 255
FATAL ERROR: unable to bind to requested udp port 43210 (ipv4)
BombSquad exited with code 255
FATAL ERROR: unable to bind to requested udp port 43210 (ipv4)
BombSquad exited with code 255
FATAL ERROR: unable to bind to requested udp port 43210 (ipv4)
BombSquad exited with code 255
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bombsquad_server", line 179, in <module>
    time.sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt
FATAL ERROR: unable to bind to requested udp port 43210 (ipv4)
```

I also tried to run `./bs_headless`

output is:

```
BombSquad Headless 1.4.125 build 14306.
FATAL ERROR: unable to bind to requested udp port 43210 (ipv4)
```

please help, what should I do?
Thank you.

Comment: See what process has port 43210 open already: `sudo lsof -i tcp:43210`

Comment: It didn't return anything

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your game is not running. Then try to start the server.